# How to get Map object from aurelia-plugins-google-maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, aurelia

I’m fairly new to both Aurelia and the Google Maps API and I’m using this google-maps plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/aurelia-plugins-google-maps

It’s working well, but I don’t completely understand how to get the Map object down into my viewModel.
Correct me if I’m wrong, from the documentation it seems like if I add the following to my constructor, I’ll be able to access the Map object via the map-created event payload:

```
this.subscriber = this.eventAggregator.subscribe('aurelia-plugins:google-maps:map-created', payload => {

    var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(39.5, -98.35);
    var proj = payload.getProjection().fromLatLngToPoint(pos);

});
```

I **do** get an object as the payload, but it doesn’t seem to be structured the way that I expect, with the getProjection method exposed. I’m sure I’m missing something stupidly crucial.

**Screenshot of the payload object from F12 tools**

[image: Screenshot of the payload object from F12 tools]